# Print statements outside of if__name__ == '__main__' are being repeated inside

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-multiprocessing

I have some code that I am trying to update and I am running into the problem of have the print statements repeat multiple times. Ideally the print statements would just show up once to notify the user what is happening then not be repeated. I am not sure what to do to fix it, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import arcpy
import CommonDirectorySearch as cds
import multiprocessing
import os
from pathlib import Path
import tempfile
import math


# Ensure that %TEMP%\mp_mosaic directory exists since we will put output there
temp_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
mosaic_root_dir = str(Path(temp_dir).joinpath("mp_mosaic"))
os.makedirs(mosaic_root_dir, exist_ok=True)

#sets the folder in which the rasters can be found
WSEUDir = 'E:\Models'
#Allows for counting the number of rasters in the directory
path, dirs, files = os.walk(WSEUDir).__next__()
#Counts the number of CPU cores the machine has
multiprocessing.cpu_count()
#Sets the number of CPU cores to use
#You should use no more than one less than the total number of cores!
c = multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2
#Set the number or rasters to mosaic, ideally the number of rasters to mosaic at a one time
#would be the total number of rasters divided by the number of CPU cores rounded down to the nearest integer
rm = int(math.floor(len(dirs)/c))
#rm = 2

print('Your computer has' ,multiprocessing.cpu_count(),'CPU cores, so',multiprocessing.cpu_count()-2, 'cores will be used')
print ('There are',(len(dirs)),'rasters to be processed')
print ('There wil be approximately',rm, 'rasters assigned to each core')

def mosaic2raster(input_raster_dirs):
    #prints the two rasters to be mosaiced
    print("mosaic2raster: " + input_raster_dirs)

    #sets where the new temp mosaiced rasters will be stored
    output_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=mosaic_root_dir).name

    # Process: Mosaic To New Raster
    #Creates the newly mosaiced raster name
    output_raster = Path(output_dir).name

    #Does the mosaic
    arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(input_raster_dirs, mosaic_root_dir,output_raster, "PROJCS['NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_Central_FIPS_4203_Feet',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Lambert_Conformal_Conic'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',2296583.333333333],PARAMETER['False_Northing',9842500.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-100.3333333333333],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_1',30.11666666666667],PARAMETER['Standard_Parallel_2',31.88333333333333],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',29.66666666666667],UNIT['Foot_US',0.3048006096012192]]", "32_BIT_FLOAT", "2", "1", "MAXIMUM", "FIRST")

    return output_dir

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Tells where the input rasters are stored and what the raster names are
    matched, input_raster_dirs = cds.find_directory_pattern("coa_100_wseu", WSEUDir)
    if matched:
        input_rasters = ";".join(p for p in input_raster_dirs)


        # Grabbing rasters to merge
        input_rasters = []
        for i in range(0, len(input_raster_dirs), rm):
            input_rasters.append(input_raster_dirs[i] + ";" + input_raster_dirs[i+1])

        # start multiprocessing worker processes using cpu cores
        with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=c) as pool:
            temp_output_dirs = pool.map(mosaic2raster, input_rasters)
            print(temp_output_dirs)
```

Gives me:

```
Your computer has 12 CPU cores, so 10 cores will be used
There are 40 rasters to be processed
There wil be approximately 4 rasters assigned to each core
Your computer has 12 CPU cores, so 10 cores will be used
There are 40 rasters to be processed
There wil be approximately 4 rasters assigned to each core
mosaic2raster: E:\Models\Barton\COA\Gaines\coa_100_wseu;E:\Models\Bear\COA\BEAR\coa_100_wseu
Your computer has 12 CPU cores, so 10 cores will be used
There are 40 rasters to be processed
There wil be approximately 4 rasters assigned to each core
mosaic2raster: E:\Models\Bear\COA\BER_T2\coa_100_wseu;E:\Models\Bear\COA\BER_T2B\coa_100_wseu
```

Comment: This isn't the *whole* script. You imported modules, please include the full code. You probably imported the script itself, so it is run as `__main__` **and** as the `scriptname` module.

Comment: In other words, it is trivial to cause the main script to be run twice, but you do have to show more of your code for me to point out where you did so.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods

Comment: Don't *put* those statements outside `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: Thanks user2357112 that did it.  I am still trying to fully understand this script and I am new to python as well, so I have a lot to learn